# How can I handle events on a select tag which is placed inside an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not the actual code, but this is basically the idea:

I have a select tag, which is inside an anchor tag.

```
<a href="#rightTab">
  <select class="tab-options">
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="2">Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3</option>
  </select>
  <span class="add-option">Add</span>
</a>
```

Clicking on `<a>` should show a tab-pane. Additionally, I should be able to choose an option from `<select>`.

Currently I'm having a problem handling events on the latter. By monitoring the log of events in Firebug, I found out that after the first click on `select` (or `option`), **mousedown** events are no longer triggered.

What events should I prevent from bubbling up?

**edit**
Some clarifications:

- Each anchor is a child of a `li` tag.  They represent objects in our model, and have a data-id attribute.

  - Besides the *add "button"*, there are two additional actions. Both two are siblings of add-option. One for showing a modal and the other for removing the current `li`

Comment: Why would you have a `select` inside an anchor?  What are you actually trying to achieve - more high level?

Comment: Originally, the anchor had an attribute **data-toggle** from Bootstrap, instead of a custom event handler. And a `select` is for adding an element of type 'value' to #rightTab when clicking on `span.add-option`

Comment: Add it where? As a text? Like "Add 1", "Add 2"?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos As a custom form within a div called #rightTab. Yes, like that. It was a design decision to use a dropdown menu instead of a button for each option, but I think we could look for another alternative if it causes us trouble

Comment: Generally using select inside anchor is a bad idea, but if you must, then you should add a corresponding event handler for your anchor and add `preventDefault` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. It took me some time to figure out but finally I found a workaround. The following event handlers did the trick

```
$('.tab-options option').on('mousedown', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});

$('.tab-options').on('change', function(e){
  $(this).trigger('blur');
  return false;
});
```

Here is a working example for you to try

```js
$('[href="#rightTab"]').on('click', function(){
 console.log("Focus on <a>");
})

$('.add-option').on('click', function(e){
 var opt = $("#container").find(':selected').text();
 alert("Selected option: " + opt);
  e.stopPropagation();
})

$('.tab-options option').on('mousedown', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});

$('select.tab-options').on('change', function(e){
  $(this).trigger('blur');
  return false;
});

$('select.tab-options').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

```css
div#container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#rightTab">
  <div id='container'>
    <select class="tab-options">
      <option value="1">Test1</option>
      <option value="2">Test2</option>
      <option value="3">Test3</option>
    </select>
    <span class="add-option">Add</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you are trying to do, but first of all you should correct your markup:

```
<select class="tab-options">
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="2">Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3</option>
</select>
<a class="add-option" href="#rightTab">
    Add
</a>
```

Then you use the `onclick` event listener of the `<a>` tag in order to capture the value of your `<select>` and put it wherever you want:

```
document.querySelector('.add-option').onclick = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    var optVal = document.querySelector('.tab-options').value;

    // Now do whatever you want with the value
}
```